# Error "invalid_grant" after using msal token from msal-react

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal-react, acquiretokensilent

I need your help with an unreachable error when msal token expire, specifically an invalid_grant error. I have a exception but this error only is showing on console. Thanks you

```
const refreshToken = async () => {
    const request = {
      account: account,
      scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"],
    };
    try {
      const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent(request);
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.accessToken);
      setToken(response.accessToken);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      const isServerError = e instanceof ServerError;
      const isInteractionRequiredError = e instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError;
      const isInvalidGrantError = (e.errorCode === "invalid_grant");
      if (isInteractionRequiredError) {
        try {
          const response = await instance.acquireTokenRedirect(request);
          localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.accessToken);
          setToken(response.accessToken);
          return;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("InteractionRequiredAuthError:" + e);
          handleError(e);
        }
      }
      if (isServerError && isInvalidGrantError && !isInteractionRequiredError) {
        localStorage.clear();
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
  };
```

I tried to catch that error but it was not possible